# Magento 2 crontab: not found

Tags: magento2, crontab, setup

I read many about problems with setup magento CRON but I don't find something about this error message with putty ssh connection:

```
Error during saving of crontab: sh: line 6: crontab: command not found
```

It is a new Magento 2.2.6 installation.

Where is my mistake?

With Mag 1.9 I had zero problems to activate the CRON. But the Mag 2 seems very complicated.

Comment: Please share what command you  have run on putty for add crontab

Comment: I use: php bin/magento cron:install

Comment: So, you want to run cron manually ?

Comment: At first yes but in future with a cronjob. With Mag 1.9 I make a cronjob that trigger the cron.php but in Mag 2 i have no plan.

Answer (score 1):

Check out, [the document](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html)

I guess that you have added cron from cpanel

In order to `php bin/magento cron:install`

First, **your current Cli** user have any record at crontab.
So, Check existing cron list using below code

> crontab -l

You have to add  magento cron

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /{ProjectPath}/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v Ran jobs by schedule >> /{ProjectPath}/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /{ProjectPath}/update/cron.php >> /{ProjectPath}/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /{ProjectPath}/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /{ProjectPath}/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

Comment: When I use the command crontab -l    I get bash: crontab: command not found

Comment: In the system.log I find these lines after main.Error: echo [2018-10-04 07:13:41] 
#~ MAG START 7886code.......
* * * * * /usr/bin/php70 /www/htdocs/xxx/xxx/magento2.2/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v \"Ran jobs by schedule\" >> /www/htdocs/xxx/xxx/magento2.2/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php70 /www/htdocs/xxx/xxx/magento2.2/update/cron.php >> /www/htdocs/xxx/xxx/magento2.2/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php70 /www/htdocs/xxx/xxx/magento2.2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /www/htdocs/xxx/xxx/magento2.2/var/log/setup.cron.log #~ MAG END 788code..

Comment: How you have add cron job for magento 1?

Comment: I can create it on the administration from my hoster. I can set a Path and time.

Comment: 3 cron , need to be at cronjobn list that is enough for magento cron

Comment: And which path to cron.php is the right one?

Comment: You don't need to add cron.php, you have to add `php bin/magento  cron:run `

Answer (score 0):

Now I find out. I cant create a crontab (Shared-Server). The only way is to create a cronjob by my hoster "all inkl" and call pub/cron.php with the cronjob. In this case this [article](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/secy/secy-cron.html) was helpfull. I've adjust the .htaccess in the /pub with password protection for the cron.php file. Now the cron works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check again cronjob installed in the environment?
You should use the command:

```
service --status-all
**or** 
ps aux | grep "cron"
```

If your environment is not installed cronjob

1, Install cronjob for ubuntu, Debian:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cron
```

2, Go to the workspace folder

```
composer install
php bin/magento cron:install
crontab -l
```